# can't access the file path because the folder name contains space and special characters

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, odbc, dbase

I am accessing DBF database file which is in hardcoded path, but the folders name contains special character for ex--BSTR-VSD,BSTR~VSD and I can't rename that.

so when i am making odbc connection say odb and then putting the query into 
odb.commandText = select * from PATH(hard coded path which contain folder names having special character) then it gives the error

Example:

System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand oCmd = oConn.CreateCommand(); 
oCmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM "+ Pathname + " where DATE_Y >=110 and DATE_M >= " + From_Month + " and DATE_D>=" + From_Day + " and DATE_Y <=110 and DATE_M <= " + To_Month + " and DATE_D<=" + To_Day + " ";

dt_Dbf.Load(oCmd.ExecuteReader());

and exception::
ERROR [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC dBase Driver] Syntax error in FROM clause.

Answer (score 0):

Surround with Brackets

```
SELECT * 
  FROM ["+ Pathname + "]
 where DATE_Y >=110 
   and DATE_M >= " + From_Month + " 
   and DATE_D>=" + From_Day + " 
   and DATE_Y <=110 
   and DATE_M <= " + To_Month + "
   and DATE_D<=" + To_Day + " "
```

You can also clean this up using things like 
    betweem StartDate and EndDate

Answer (score 0):

Why not using **[Parametrized Query](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738521.aspx)**?  You can use [OdbcParameter class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.odbc.odbcparameter.aspx).

> **MSDN:** It matches the entire length of the string, including any padding trailing spaces.

```
        System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand oCmd = oConn.CreateCommand();
        oCmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM  @pathname where DATE_Y >=110 and DATE_M >= @from_Month and DATE_D>= @from_Day and DATE_Y <=110 and DATE_M <= @to_Month and DATE_D<= @to_Day";
        oCmd.Parameters.Add(new OdbcParameter("@pathname", Pathname));
        oCmd.Parameters.Add(new OdbcParameter("@from_Month", From_Month));
        oCmd.Parameters.Add(new OdbcParameter("@to_Month", To_Month));
        oCmd.Parameters.Add(new OdbcParameter("@from_Day", From_Day));
        oCmd.Parameters.Add(new OdbcParameter("@to_Day", To_Day));
```